# R create reference manual with R CMD check

Tags: r, package, reference-manual

I am writing an R package and would like to make a pdf reference manual of all functions in the package. I understood from [here](http://grokbase.com/p/r/r-devel/124dzqqxhg/rd-creating-a-reference-manual-during-r-cmd-build) that `R CMD check` automatically creates a reference manual.

[Here](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/system/r-pkg-tut/) I read that a manual entry is created "of the functions you listed in the export section of NAMESPACE".

My NAMESPACE file looks as follows:

```
# Export all names
exportPattern(".")

# Import all packages listed as Imports or Depends
import(
  LIM
)
```

so I thought everything will be exported. During `R CMD check` on the package directory, at the very end it says:

```
 * checking PDF version of manual ... OK
```

However, I do not find a reference manual in my package directory (I would assume it would be in inst/doc). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`R CMD check` creates a directory `PACKAGE.RCheck`. In this directory you could find the file `PACKAGE-manual.pdf`.

Comment: The `PACKAGE-manual.pdf` is located one folder above the package directory, in  `../package.Rcheck`.

Answer (score 85):

Another way is to create the reference manual directly using:

```
R CMD Rd2pdf mypackage
```

where `mypackage` is the folder containing your R package code folder structure including the `man` folder with your .Rd files.

For some reason I never get the reference manual during build or check in RStudio, maybe because I've missed a setting somewhere. But running the command like this works fine as well.

Comment: Just tried it, it works well! Thanks for pointing out `Rd2pdf`!

Comment: Same problem as above, solved thanks to your suggestion. I really do not understand why Rstudio messes up so much.

Comment: While this is useful, it has a feature (?) that it does not respect .Rbuildignore

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. It seems that when you click Build or Check in Rstudio (when using devtools), by default arguments of '--no-manual' are added to the R CMD options.

I solved this by manually giving the arguments in the R command prompt:

```
library(devtools)

check(cleanup = FALSE,manual = TRUE,path = getwd())

# without running the examples
check(cleanup = FALSE,args = c('--no-examples'),manual = TRUE,path = getwd())
```

In this case, a folder called package.Rcheck will contain the manual as package-manual.pdf

Also check for any errors in the output during the check. There might be characters that might crash the documentation.

Comment: see RStudio preferences to change this easily

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround is to produce it with:

```
build_manual(path=getwd())
#or
check(manual = TRUE, args="--output=~/folder/subfolder")
```