# Creating Package Documentation with RStudio?

Tags: r, package

I managed to create a package using RStudio and roxygen2. The whole package-creating process worked without any errors and warnings. Anyway, my question is how do I create a PDF documentation of my package and its functions? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean the pdf manual?  I don't think there's a handy `devtools` function for that (but I could be wrong).  Try running `system('R CMD Rd2pdf /path/to/mypackage')`.

You'll need a working LaTeX distribution to make pdfs. [See also this discussion on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986422/r-create-reference-manual-with-r-cmd-check).

Comment: Thanks a lot. The linked question solves my problem.