# Making an R package PDF manual using devtools

Tags: r, pdf, devtools, manual, roxygen2

I am making an R package using devtools and roxygen2. I can get a PDF manual using R CMD but I am really curious as to whether this can be done using devtools. devtools' build(), check(), install() all don't make a PDF manual. Is this tied to making vignettes?

I have read and referred to a similar thread [Package development : location of pdf manual and vignette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983177/package-development-location-of-pdf-manual-and-vignette/30607455#30607455)

Answer (score 37):

After you install it, you can use:

```
pack <- "name_of_your_package"
path <- find.package(pack)
system(paste(shQuote(file.path(R.home("bin"), "R")),
    "CMD", "Rd2pdf", shQuote(path)))
```

Comment: is it possible to just add a "Introduction" page to the pdf manual generated by `R CMD check `  ?

Comment: @joel.wilson please start a new question

Comment: i did so.. here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935136/include-a-introduction-section-to-pdf-manual-of-r-package

Answer (score 26):

There is

```
devtools::build_manual()
```

Maybe also

```
devtools::check(manual=TRUE)
```

could work.

Comment: `devtools::build_manual()` works when I run it on Linux, but not if I run it on Windows. +1

Answer (score 0):

For the PDF manual of one specific function, you can run

```
fun <- "name_of_function"
help(fun, package = "name_of_package", help_type = "pdf")
system(paste0("open ",  fun, ".pdf"))
```

assuming you have the package installed.