# Getting R function help through help_console function from noamtools package to be used in .Rnw document

Tags: r, function, noamtools

I want to include help of `R` functions into `.Rnw` document using `help_console` function from `noamtools` package which can be installed from [github](https://github.com/noamross/noamtools) using the following comand:

```
devtools::install_github('noamross/noamtools', build_vignettes = TRUE)
```

Minimum working example is given below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<< label=Test, echo=FALSE >>=
library(noamtools)
# help_console(topic="mean", format = "latex")
help_console(topic="mean", format = "Rd")
@ 

\end{document}
```

I'm not getting the correct output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to include the line

```
\usepackage{Rd}
```

in the beginning of the .Rnw file and then use

```
help_console(topic="mean", format="latex")
```

For example, put the following in a file, say `test.Rnw` and compile to produce documentation about the function `mean`. Note that `results=tex` ensures that the Latex code produced by `R` is actually created like  Latex code.

```
% devtools::install_github('noamross/noamtools', build_vignettes = TRUE)
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{Rd} % Rstudio will be able to find this .sty file

\begin{document}

<<label=Test, results=tex>>=
library(noamtools)
help_console(topic="mean", format = "latex")
@ 

\end{document}
```

Which produces a pdf which looks like this,

[image: mean]

Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607496/making-an-r-package-pdf-manual-using-devtools) helped me realize that the `Rd.sty` file needed to be included. Running the following code

```
pack <- "ggplot2"
path <- find.package(pack)
system(paste(shQuote(file.path(R.home("bin"), "R")),
             "CMD", "Rd2pdf --no-clean", shQuote(path)))
# .Rd2xxxx directory created
# cd .Rd2xxxx
```

You can look inside the created directory named something like `.Rd2xxxx` to find `Rd2.tex` which shows what is put in the Latex documentation files which R creates.