# Edit the default PDF manual generated while building R package

Tags: r, package

I have succsesfully performed the below steps to create my own R package :

1. created skeleton of the package and pasted `.Rd`, `NAMESPACE` and `DESCRIPTION` files.
2. executed `R CMD check package_name` : no errors, it also generated 2 pdf's

One of which contains the output's from `.Rd` file examples and second is the PDF manual that comprises the documentation itself.

My question is how to make edits to this manual created, such as to change the font size or add an Introductory page to this manual? I read that `roxygen` / `devtools` might help but no resource on that was attained. I also went through the Writing R Extensions link that is available but couldn't help me.

Would there be a way using `Rd2pdf`? but such that even non .Rd files are also included

Comment: The official doc page about writing R Extensions: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html (see if Section 2  can help). Consider also that you can create a `inst/` folder in your package to attach examples/documents/whatever to your package (near the end of Section 1.1.5).

Comment: @nicola thanks for this link.. i actually had went through this but missed out the `inst` folder. let me try this

Comment: @nicola i tried having a `inst` folder and included sample files in it. However when i ran `R CMD check ...`, those sample files were just included in the installation subdirectory as mentioned and NOT in the pdf manual generated

Comment: Yes, indeed. That was just kind of a work-around. Don't think (but not sure at all) that you can change the style of the doc. You can however reference to your Introduction document in the manual and document how you can access it (typically by `system.file("extradoc/Introduction.pdf",package="myPackage")` assuming that you put the introduction document inside the `extradoc` folder).