# Generating a the package documentation file

Tags: r, roxygen2

I'm in the process of putting together an R package, using devtools. It seems that most packages on CRAN has a documentation file that covers all documented functions. How do I build this?

I have pkgname.R, like so:

```
#' _PACKAGE
#' @encoding utf-8
#'
#' @title Show where Adam bought the beer.
#'
#' @description The package consists of diverse functions to analyse
#' the path between Adam and the beer.
#'
#' @author Rolf Marvin Bøe Lindgren <rolf@grendel.no>
#' @docType package
#' @name Tarnation
#' 
#' 
"_PACKAGE"
#> [1] "_PACKAGE"
#'
```

This generates a nice help file.

I assume that there's either an easy way or a cumbersome way to generate a comprehensive documentation file. A pointer to relevant documentation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Processing-documentation-files

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986422/r-create-reference-manual-with-r-cmd-check

Answer (score 0):

```
R CMD check <packagename>
```

generates it in `<packagename>.Rcheck`