# Faster way of generating R package documentation (i.e. pdf manual) in roxygen2?

Tags: r, roxygen2

For a package made with roxygen2, documentaiton can be generated with

```
R CMD check package_name
```

Is there a faster way to generate the package manual (pdf)?

Note: it must work for roxygen2-made packages. I tried ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22313712/5783745) method, but it doesn't appear to work for a roxygen2-made package)

Comment: Do `devtools::build_manual`

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent that's perfect. Thanks!