# R CMD Check, '--no-manual': How to change this option?

Tags: r, package

There are similar questions [R create reference manual with R CMD check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986422/r-create-reference-manual-with-r-cmd-check). However, I still can fix my problem with `R CMD Check`.

When `R CMD Check`, it indicates:

```
-- R CMD check results ----------------------------------- chest 0.0.1.0000 ----
Duration: 1m 32.1s

0 errors v | 0 warnings v | 0 notes v

R CMD check succeeded
```

But without producing the Reference Manual. When I check the log file, it says `* using options '--no-manual --as-cran'`. I have tried to change the `Project option`, then `Build tools`, then `Check package R CMD check additional options` without any success. What should I do to turn off `--no-manual` option? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be running `devtools::check()` from the RStudio menus.  I don't know if there's a way to set these options from the menus, but you can set them from the command line by running

```
devtools::check(manual = TRUE)
```

Comment: It works beautifully! You ended my many hours of stress. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `R CMD check pkgtarfile`, [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/PkgUtils.html), directly in a terminal, where pkgtarfile is the 'tar' file you obtain with `devtools::build()` or `R CMD build pkgdirs`. `R CMD check` generates the pdf manual by default and can be found in the folder pkgname.Rcheck.