# Is there a special .Rmd template to create R package vignette in pdf?

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, r-package

I'm developing my first R package and I'm trying to produce a pdf vignette for the package. I have read some documents and online tutorial about producing package vignettes by the tools such as rmarkdown and knitr. I implemented some steps and produced a pdf vignette. However, having a look on the pdf vignettes of some packages like:

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmarkdown/rmarkdown.pdf
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cluster/cluster.pdf
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmom/lmom.pdf
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmomRFA/lmomRFA.pdf
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/e1071.pdf

, it seems that there is a special template to produce pdf vignettes of R packages. Is there such a template? If yes, how can I find and use it?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: look there: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/package-template.html

Comment: As far as I know, these files are created by CRAN itself. They are based on the /man .Rd documents.

Comment: @manro Thanks you! I have read the book and used the guidance but I couldn't produce the pdf in the desirable format or structure. However, I think that I've made a mistake in somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You may be right. I think that I've mistaken Reference Manuals as Vignettes. @tacoman

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments I've mistaken reference manuals as vignettes and so, I hadn't be able to find the correct answer. When I searched by using the correct keywords, I found the correct answer:

- https://devtools.r-lib.org/reference/build_manual.html
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rd2md/vignettes/Introduction.html
- [R create reference manual with R CMD check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986422/r-create-reference-manual-with-r-cmd-check)